# Need an email sent automatically when a customer abandon cart

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using Drupal 7 with drupal commerce. 
I require an email sent automatically to those customers who abandon their cart.

Is there any way?

Comment: When do you consider that the user left the cart?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the commerce [notification module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_notification):

> This module allows you to notify your customers by email about their
>   abandoned their cart.

This module is 100% integrated with the Commerce Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module

**How does that work ?**

Go to the view page : /admin/commerce/orders/abandoned_carts Select
    the customers you want to notify (the module does not allow you to
    notify a user more than once... Don't be a spammer ^^) Select the
    component : "Notify the user of his abandoned cart" and click on
    "Execute"

Although it has not a estable release you can download it from [git](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_notification/git-instructions) with a git clone:

```
git clone --branch 7.x-1.x http://git.drupal.org/project/commerce_notification.git
cd commerce_notification
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But I have already tried Commercie Notification and I see a 403 error when I try to access www.mysite.com/admin/commerce/orders/abandoned_carts Module is enabled. In its open issues many users are facing the same problem. Is there a way to fix it? Or is any other module / solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The admin/commerce/orders/abandoned_carts view had not being added to the code it self in 7.x-1.x branch, you should clone the branch new-table instead.

See this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2283231)

Despite of the view not having a url, you can create a new view with the same filter criteria/fields.

But when i active the bulk operation "Notify the user of his abandoned cart" created by this module i get an ajax error, but that should be asked in another question.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issues as the previous posters and was frustrated by the lack of solutions or modules out there so I rolled my own.

My solution uses Views, [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules), [Commerce ProdNodeLink](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_prodnodelink), Rules, PHP Filter, and Mimemail and runs on hourly cron.

### Create a Views block

The views block will output a list of order numbers, first names and email addresses that will be used by Rules.

- *Format:* Unformatted list
- *Advanced:* Add relationship to "Commerce Order: Referenced customer profile" and be sure to select the profile related to billing information (commerce_customer_billing)
- *Fields:*

  - Order Number
  - First Name from the related billing profile
  - Email Address from the billing profile
- *Filter Criteria:*

  - "Commerce Order: Order state" is one of "Shopping cart" or "checkout"
  - "Commerce Order: Order status" is one of "Shopping cart (Shopping cart)", "Checkout: Checkout (Checkout)", "Checkout: Billing Information (Checkout)", "Checkout: Shipping (Checkout)", "Checkout: Review (Checkout)".  Your mileage may vary on this one.  Essentially you want to choose any status including cart through the last page of checkout in your setup, not including the order confirmation page.  ;)
  - "Commerce Customer profile: Email address (field_email_address)" should be set to "Is not empty (NOT NULL)".  We want to make sure that there is a value for the email address.
  - "Commerce Order: Order total (commerce_order_total:amount)" should be set to greater than 0. This is a second control since a user could go through checkout but then remove all products from the cart.  We don't want to email those people.
  - "Commerce Order: Updated date" should be set to "In between". The "value type" should be set to "An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"" where the Min value is "-2 hours" and the Max value is "-1 hours". We only want to fetch abandoned orders that are between 1 and 2 hours old. This way we avoid our system from emailing people too quickly (e.g., a user going through checkout at 1:59 won't be emailed by the cron trigger at 2:00).

Your view may or may not be empty if you don't have any abandoned carts in the specified window.

### Set up the Views Rules display

While in your view from step 1, click "Add" and select "Rules".  This will create a rules block for your view that you can use within Rules to iterate over.

Click "edit field info" next to "Row variables" and enable each of the 3 fields you added in step 1.  I checked "Use rendered result" for each.  The data type should be "Text" for each field.

Save your view.

### Set up the Rule

- *Event:* "Cron maintenance tasks are performed"
- *Conditions:* "Execute custom PHP code"

  - Value: `return views_get_view_result('YOUR_VIEWS_BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME', 'display_title');`
- *Actions:*

  1. Click "Add view loop" and choose the view you just created. Doing this will expose the view to rules and allow you to loop through the items in the view.
  2. Click "Send HTML e-mail"

     - Give your email a machine name
     - Use the email address token (mine was [field-email-address:value]) as the "To:" value.  Check your Replacement Patterns or PHP Evaluation variables for clues here.
     - Enter other details if needed (bcc, cc, etc.)
     - The Body has PHP in it and is styled to have a header and a footer.  In the body the list of products that were left inside the cart are output in a table with an image on the left and product title on the right, each of which links to the product node alias on your website. Mine is like so (be sure to change your variables the ones supplied by your PHP Evaluation):

[The only way I could get the code block to show is to include this line (ugh):]

```
<table style='font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;'><tbody>
<?php
$product_ids = array();
foreach (entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order_number)->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
  if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->type->value(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {
    $product_ids[] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->raw();
  }
}

foreach ($product_ids as $p) {
  // Get the product details by the Commerce function
  $product = commerce_product_load($p);

  // Get the product by Entity in order to eventually retrieve the node ID from Commerce ProdLink module
  $product_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $p);
  $display_node_ids = $product_wrapper->display_node_ids->value();

  foreach ($display_node_ids as $nid) {
    print '<tr><td style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;"><a href="' . url('node/' . $nid, $options) . '"><img src="' . $product->field_image_square["und"][0]["uri"] . '" height="125" width="125" /></a></td><td style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;"><a href="' . url('node/' . $nid, $options) . '">' . $product->title . '</a></td></tr>';
  }
}
// Write to the log
watchdog('abandoned cart email', 'Abandoned Cart Notification Email Sent to !email (cart !cart)', array( '!email' => $field_email_address, '!cart' => $order_number ), WATCHDOG_INFO);
?>
</tbody></table>
```

And for anyone who is wondering what $options is, it's just a variable declared earlier for adding UTM codes to the link:

```
<?php
// Setup URL arguments for tracking
$options = array('absolute' => TRUE, 'base_url' => 'https://example.com', 'https' => TRUE, 'query' => array('utm_source' => 'email', 'utm_medium' => 'email', 'utm_campaign' => 'abandoned cart email', 'utm_content' => 'product link'));
?>
```

3. Indent the "Send HTML e-mail" element

You should now have an automated abandoned cart email checker running hourly!